# Create a Chat Bubble In Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am trying to create a chat bubble with some text.For this I am create Three Layoutouts,Inside of main Linear Layout I am using FramLayout,I am setting a 9-patch background  To this Framlayout.Inside of Framlayout I am adding one more RelativeLayout where I am placing my three textViews and one imageView.but type long text it goes outside of FramLayout border.I don't know what I am doing wrong or what I am missing.When I am using small text it remain fit but with big text it goes out from even Background Border of FramLayout.In attachment I am showing my bubble and yahoo IM bubble.I am trying to create same like yahoo but with some different style.Please give me your suggestion.I try a lot with different ways but not get success.Thanks in advance . . [image]
Here I am placing my Layoutfile

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/linearListLayout1">

       <FrameLayout
           android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:background="@drawable/bubbleblue" >

            <RelativeLayout
              android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
              android:minHeight="100dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/chattitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

               <TextView android:id="@+id/chatdate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

               <TextView android:id="@+id/chatText"
                   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chatstatus"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/chattitle"
                   android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/chatstatus"
                   android:text="TextView" />

              <ImageView
                  android:id="@+id/chatstatus"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:src="@drawable/add_picture"
                  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/chatdate"
                  android:minHeight="2dip"
                  android:maxWidth="2sp"
                  android:maxHeight="2sp"
                  android:layout_marginRight="2dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
  </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Well we'd need to see the layout file.  I'm partial to a Linear/RelativeLayouts for this sort of thing.  FrameLayouts can get kinda hairy IMO.

Comment: Have you tried messing with padding?

Comment: Yes I use also try it with padding and also use margin.

Comment: I've written a blog post about [android chat bubbles](http://adilsoomro.blogspot.com/2012/12/android-listview-with-speech-bubble.html), you can find the open-source code there too.

Comment: Have a look at this project : https://github.com/madhur/android-chat-starter

Answer (score 4):

When creating your .9patch image, you also must specify a content area, which you define with the left, and bottom pixels. [Check out this.](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html)

Comment: Hi for 9-patch I do the same things as it given on your link.http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: @user717572 page not found.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
[image]  and 
[image]

for background of your root layout item.

right click on images and select **Save target as**.