# Balloon in Chatting Android Application

Tags: java, android, xml, chat, balloon

I've to develop an android application that allows users to chat I want to make textView  that handle their conversations in Balloon as shown in the picture below ,,

can anyone inform me how can I do that ????

thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Hi for this you need to create Custom Adapter.using View holder you can add and change balloon inside of bubble,I did this same this in my application it working great . .

Comment: @aftab could you share your code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create two balloon images (for sent and received messages), make them 9 patch and set them as background to a layout which contains conversation.

Comment: first thanks for answering me, second: create two balloon images (for sent and received messages), I did that ,  make them 9 patch: can u explain more I'm biginner, and set them as background to an layout which contains conversation : what's the type of the containers should I use ??

Comment: check http://android10.org/index.php/articlesother/279-draw-9-patch-tutorial and http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/ tutorials for nine patch. As for containers, use a listView which contains two textViews (for send and received messages) if you want a simple look and put your textViews in a linearLayout. Set your images as background to your linearLayout

Answer (score 1):

You will use 9 Patch images for this.

for showing them, you will use `ListView` and each row item will contain text and that 9 patch chat bubble background.

Lot of discussion are available:

- I've written a blog post about [android chat bubbles](http://adilsoomro.blogspot.com/2012/12/android-listview-with-speech-bubble.html), you can find the open-source code there too.
- For example this *stackoverflow* [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9399612/593709).
- [Speech bubble popups containing a View](http://www.actionshrimp.com/2011/05/speech-bubble-popups-containing-a-view-for-android-mapview/) post will also help you.