# Android custom special textview background

Tags: android, layout, background, custom-controls

I am creating a chat client demo and I want to design an layout for chat item. I want to apply 2 different backgrounds for TextView (contains chat message) when chatting. So how can I design this background for making textView looks good when chat message is short/long? I don't think 9path can do it well for me.

Sorry, this is image link for what I said.
[enter link description here](http://ns6.upanh.com/b6.s34.d4/899d96a76247decf78d78ae6a323d8d3_51138676.yahoochat.png)

Comment: be specific for asking your question.. add more description

Comment: what's wrong with 9-patch, and why do you think it is not fit ?

Comment: [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9399612/1050058). Elaborate what your issue is.

Comment: I don't know how to draw background drawable like that to apply to textview. That background likes a Callout, with an arrow, bright color, ...I draw a callout with MS Office, and create 9path from that. When text inside textview is so long, the arrow changes the size (longer, worse). I try to apply but it can not beautiful like Yahoo! in the link.