# Bubble Chat layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an layout

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/chat_bg">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="32dip"
        android:layout_height="32dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar_1_1"        
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5sp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

and in the java code i have :

```
LayoutParams lp1 = (LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
    LayoutParams lp2 = (LayoutParams) avatarView.getLayoutParams();
    if (incoming) {
        lp1.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        lp2.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speech_bubble_green);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lp1);
        avatarView.setLayoutParams(lp2);
    } else {
        lp1.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        lp2.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speech_bubble_orange);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lp1);
        avatarView.setLayoutParams(lp2);
    }
```

I want the incomming message and its avatar will be align **right** like Viber, outgoing on the **left**, but all message now is align **left**

Thanks for all suggestions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a Chat Bubble In Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399612/create-a-chat-bubble-in-android)

Comment: github source 1. https://github.com/NakedSwrod/Android-Speech-Bubble 2. https://github.com/NakedSwrod/AndroidChatBubbles

Comment: You should use a ListView, make a layout for each, define two view types in your adapter and have the adapter switch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution here

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/background"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingRight="4dip"
android:paddingBottom="4dip"
android:background="@drawable/chat_bg">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/avatar"
    android:layout_width="32dip"
    android:layout_height="32dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
    android:src="@drawable/avatar_1_1"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatar"
    android:paddingLeft="4dip"
    />
```

And here java code :

```
RelativeLayout bg = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.background);         
        if (incoming) {
            textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speech_bubble_orange);

            bg.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
        } else {
            textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.speech_bubble_green);

            LayoutParams avatarParams = (LayoutParams) avatarView.getLayoutParams();
            avatarParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
            avatarView.setLayoutParams(avatarParams);

            /*android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/avatar"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dip"*/
            LayoutParams tvParam = (LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
            tvParam.removeRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF);
            tvParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.avatar);
            textView.setLayoutParams(tvParam);

            bg.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        <!-- android:layout_gravity="left" -->
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/avatar"
                android:layout_width="32dip"
                android:layout_height="32dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
                android:src="@drawable/controller"
        />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:text="asd"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5sp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

To set gravity in your Activity:

```
LinearLayout lp = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.background);
lp.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
lp.setGravity(Gravity.Left);
```

So, the only thing that i changed is in your `LinearLayout` in XML file, change `layout_width` from `fill_parent` to `wrap_content`

---

**EDIT:** (due to more information)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/background"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/avatar2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text2">
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/avatar"
                android:layout_width="32dip"
                android:layout_height="32dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dip"
                android:src="@drawable/controller"
                />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/text2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/avatar">
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:text="asd"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So, use

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)yourLayout.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.id_to_be_left_of);
//params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.id_to_be_left_of);
yourLayout.setLayoutParams(params); //causes layout update
```

Do not forget that dependencies **cannot be circular**

Comment: If the `layout_width` is changed to `wrapped_content` then no matter what gravity it has on horizontal axis the inner content will remain in the same place, and that will depend to parent view, right? I believe the `layout_width` should be `match_parent` and changing the `gravity` will do the trick.

Comment: @gunar in designer if I add `android:layout_gravity="left"` or `android:layout_gravity="right"` i see the difference.

Comment: Then it doesn't matter that much since that property is passed to its parent in the end and since it seems this is a root container it will in the end occupy the whole screen. I am also thinking that the solution is the `setGravity` method.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your answers. layout `match_parent` and `setGravity` just work fines, but as i described, i want the avatar view is right_of text view when layout align right.