# How to add items into listview on button click?

Tags: android, button, android-listview

In my application,there is a listview which contains some data.There is an edittext and a button in the same activity.When i type something in the edittext,i want to add that text as new item into ListView on a button click.How to do that?Please help...

Here is a sample of my code...

This is my customList adapter

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    ListView list;

    String[] web = {
    "Google Plus",
        "Twitter",
        "Windows",
        "Bing",
        "Itunes",
        "Wordpress",
        "Drupal"
} ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button clicked...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
    });

    CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, web);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()  {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         }
     });
```

This is my adapter class

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private final Activity context;
private final String[] web;

public CustomList(Activity context,  String[] web) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
    this.context = context;
    this.web = web;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
   LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
   View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
   TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);


   txtTitle.setText(web[position]);


  return rowView;
}
}
```

Comment: get text from editText on Button click. add it to the array and call notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter. You could use a ArrayList also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare

```
final ArrayList<String> dataset = new ArrayList<String>();
Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
final CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, dataset, imageId);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) 
{
   dataset.add(et.getText().toString());
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
});
```

Then

```
private  ArrayList<String>  web;
public CustomList(Activity context, ArrayList<String> web, Integer[] imageId) {
super(context, R.layout.list_single, web);
```

And in getView

```
txtTitle.setText(web.get(position));
```

Edit:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
EditText ed;
CustomList adapter;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ListView lv = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ed= (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    adapter = new CustomList(this,list);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            list.add(ed.getText().toString());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

    });

}
}
```

activity_main.xml;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

CustomList

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private  ArrayList<String >web;
LayoutInflater mInflater;
public CustomList(Context context, ArrayList<String> web) {
    super(context, 0, web);
    mInflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.web = web;

}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

   View rowView= mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
   TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
   txtTitle.setText(web.get(position));
  return rowView;
}
}
```

list_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Snap

[image]

Comment: @kalyanpvs actually a model class would be better. gonna edit it

Comment: and maybe you could also correct op's getView in order to avoid the double memory allocation.

Comment: @Raghunandan yes need to be change getView also to make it perfect.

Comment: no viewholder in this case. Remove the inflater and call the super `View rowView = super.getView(positiom, .... ) `

Comment: @Nevaeh sorry my computer is giving problems had to restart

Comment: @Nevaeh should the item's have textview or imageview?? and why do you web??

Comment: Its ok.I just want to add text.no need of image

Comment: @Nevaeh then in your getView you also have imageview

Comment: just ignore the imageview please.

Comment: @Nevaeh give few minutes will edit it. My comp is giving me problems

Comment: Yeah okie.I deleted the image view from my code.Now just String array only.Please see updated question.

Comment: Can u please reply soon ?

Comment: @Nevaeh Now check the update with snap shot also and also if it helps don't forget to mark the answer as accepted by clicking on the tick next to the answer

Comment: @Raghunandan can u please help me with another problem ?

Comment: @Nevaeh new problem. post a new questio with specifi details

Comment: This is a chat application in which i am working.I am confused in creating 9patch image for the chat bubble.Could u please help me in doing this ?

Comment: @Nevaeh http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399612/create-a-chat-bubble-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Add item in your **arraylist/list/Array**, and then **notify** your list by using:

```
adapterObject.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: How to add the item into my list ?Can u show me a sample code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
ArrayList<String> web=new ArrayList<String>();
   b.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) 
       {
             web.add(et.getText().toString());
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

After updating the web and ImageId.
You have to call the notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter.

**Try this code with changes:**

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);


            Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     CustomList adapter = new CustomList(MainActivity.this, web, imageId);
            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View arg0) 
                 {
    //update the data on the web and imageID
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button clicked...", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //call the notifydatasetChanged on the adapter
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                  }
               });


        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() 
        {

             @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thats too on onclick event of the button, but before calling the notifyDAtaSetChanged method. @Nevaeh