# Alternate ListItem Styles

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to make a `list_item_view` similar to

[image]

can anybody help me create it...

What i have tried

1. made separate view for the list items i.e `list_item_even` and 'list_item_odd'
2. for brevity i'll only show one of them, below is the code for `list_item_even`

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/displaysms_lastmsgtime"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/displaysms_contactname"
       android:layout_below="@+id/displaysms_contactname"
       android:gravity="right"
       android:text="88:88"
       android:textColor="#10bcc9"
       android:textSize="12sp"
       android:textStyle="bold" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/displaysms_msgtext"
       android:layout_width="260dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton1"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton1"
       android:background="#fff"
       android:shadowColor="@color/textShadow"
       android:shadowDx="1"
       android:shadowDy="1"
       android:text="hi"
       android:textColor="@color/textColor"
       android:textSize="16sp" />



   <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:layout_below="@+id/displaysms_lastmsgtime"
       android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/displaysms_contactname"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/displaysms_msgtext"
       android:text="john"
       android:textColor="#fff"
       android:textSize="15sp"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:typeface="sans" />
   ```

and here is output

[image]

is it possible to create the `yellow` icon without using image and place an image inside it?
plaese help, Regards

Comment: Your title is misleading. I suggest you edit it to reflect the actual problem. It does not seem like your problem is with implementing alternating list-item styles.

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9399612/create-a-chat-bubble-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to create the yellow icon without using image and place
>   an image inside it?

Maybe, but why put an unnecessary constraint on yourself? You can use a 9patch drawable for the yellow background thing if you're worried about stretching the pointed part. You can learn all about 9patch [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html).

Answer (score 0):

i think you better off defining the layout programatically and check the row number if odd use one layout if even use a different one 
 if (row%2==0) use one layout
 else use a different one

Comment: i dont have a problem doing that, already taken care of it inside the list adapter, the problem is i cannot replicate the layout as shown in the first pic, i have attached the output of my layout (fig:2) which is far from similar to first one